# Calling Rotate Feature tool from QGIS Python Console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, features, qgis-python-console, rotate

To rotate feature(s) in QGIS you need to be in editing mode, select one or more features then use *'Rotate Feature'* tool present inside Advanced Digitizing Toolbar:

[image]

But how can we call this action from Python code to plug it somewhere in a plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this script:

```py
# Get all actions
actions = iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction)

# Check the action 
action = [x for x in actions if x.objectName()=='mActionRotateFeature'][0]

# Run the action
action.trigger()
```

Comment: Thankyou Kadir,
Also can you help me out in uising it without a vector layer maybe on a QgsRubberBand prior to creating a layer.

Comment: @GothamChess I read your other question. I have no idea. Actually, I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: Problem: This action can only be called after making a editing enabled vector layer. But what I am doing is allowing user to make as many RubberBands as required  be it QgsRectangle or Polygon and afterwards making a vector layer housing all those polygons....In-between user may want to rotate the rubberbands too for that purpose right now I am manually setting the rotation of QgsRubberBands using a doublespinbox.Using this tool makes it more user friendly.But I am unable to get a handle to it for QgsRubberBands.

Comment: With your code the 'Rotate Feature' will only be checked, `action.trigger()` in this case is equal to `action.setChecked(True)`. Seems like the edit mode should firstly be applied !

Comment: @Taras Thanks, you are right, I am aware of that. The user has already activated editing mode.

Comment: True! I will live my comment as a small pointer ^_^