# Using "Toggle Editing" button from PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, toolbar

I am building a plugin in Qgis 3.24
Now, I want to access the "Toggle Editing" button from the Vector ToolBar using Python.
Is it possible?

Edit - I want to access rotate feature, Scale feature, Delete part etc. from the toolbar using Python.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Advanced Digitizing Toolbar" ?

Comment: Yes , I am talking about Advanced digitizing toolbar

Comment: How to trigger it?

Comment: How do I use the 'rotate feature' after triggering the action?

Comment: Please avoid asking new questions in comments, Instaed, use [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button to ask additional questions. You are asking "how to access rotate etc. actions". "How to use rotate etc actions" is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Qt answer :

```py
edit_action = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QAction, "mActionToggleEditing")
edit_action.trigger()
```

Answer (score 7):

The first option is simply by using the [`startEditing()`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1cb9fe1007c931a0e78195607ace518e) method of the `QgsVectorLayer` class.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
```

The second option, as was suggested by @J.Monticolo, is to apply the [`edit()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/edit.html). However, remember that it will also automatically call `layer.commitChanges()` on success.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
with edit(layer):
    # do something here
```

The third option is to penetrate the [`QApplication`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html) class, and try to find it's *'Digitizing Toolbar'*-child.

```py
all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
for widget in all_widgets:
    if widget.windowTitle() == 'Digitizing Toolbar':
        for action in widget.actions():
            if action.objectName() == 'mActionToggleEditing':
                action.trigger()
```

P.S. Thank you @KadirŞahbaz for a tip with [`trigger()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qaction.html#trigger) method of the `QAction` class.

---

To get to the *'Rotate Feature(s)'*-action from the ["Advanced Digitizing Toolbar"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#advanced-digitizing):

```py
all_widgets = QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
for widget in all_widgets:
    if widget.windowTitle() == 'Advanced Digitizing Toolbar':
        for action in widget.actions():
            if action.objectName() == 'mActionRotateFeature':
                print(dir(action))
```

Please, also consider @KadirŞahbaz's answer in this thread: [Calling Rotate Feature tool from QGIS Python Console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404788/calling-rotate-feature-from-python-code-in-qgis?rq=1)

Comment: I have edited my question to exactly what i need

Comment: Hi Taras. `setChecked` doesn't activate buttons on Digitizing Toolbar, just sets the editing button checked. A better approach is to use `action.trigger()`.

Comment: How do I use the 'rotate feature' after triggering the action? @Taras

Comment: @BenStone If Taras' answer is helpful and solves your issue, please consider upvoting by clicking on the arrows next to the score and accepting it by clicking on the checkmark ✓. This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I want to give a Qgis message saying editing is on /off , how to do that? @Kadir Şahbaz

Comment: Use `action.isChecked()` for Toggle Editing action.

Comment: I suggest asking it as a new question, instead of editing the old question\

Comment: I got the answer. I just reversed the condition. But Can we toggle editing off again with the help of another button?